# Display listbox.items in foreach

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, listbox

```
class SymbolClass
{
    public string Symbol{ get; set; }

    public SymbolClass(string symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
    }
}


public static IEnumerable<SymbolClass> ReadCsv(string fileName)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"));

    return lines.Select(line =>
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(';');

            return new SymbolClass(data[0]);
        });
}
```

Create wpf window:

```
ListBox.ItemsSource = SymbolClass.ReadCsv("example");
```

and XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" DisplayMemberPath="Symbol">
```

and now I want to start `foreach` in this listbox

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in ListBox.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

but I don't see

```
DisplayMemberPath="Symbol"
```

I see only

```
Namespace.SymbolClass
```

But if I set a breakout, I see that `SymbolClass` get properties which I want to display.

How can I display this `DisplayMemberPath="Symbol"`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, it was mistake - need var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your edit, I propose that what you *really* want in your code is this:

```
foreach (Namespace.ClassName item in ListBox.Items)
{
    Message.Box(item.Symbol);
}
```

C# will generate the code for you to cast to the type you specify. So all that's left is for you to display the property you are interested in.